# Gerrit to Sonar Plugin ignores noIssuesScore

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, gerrit, sonar-gerrit

In our build (Jenkins Pipeline Script), the *Sonar Gerrit Plugin* should just add a review when there are issues. Otherwise it should just add the comment, but skip the score:

```
sonarToGerrit(
    sonarURL: env.'SONAR_HOST_URL',
    severity: 'INFO',
    postScore: true,
    category: 'Code-Review',
    issuesScore: '-1',
    noIssuesScore: '0'
)
```

But it seems the `noIssuesScore` is ignored. It always posts `+1` when there are no violations.

We use the most recent release `2.1` with the latest Jenkins lts version `2.89.2`.

Thanks in advance for any help!

PS: The *Pipeline Syntax* generator seems to be broken, too. It always just prints `step <object of type org.jenkinsci.plugins.sonargerrit.SonarToGerritPublisher>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check out the new version 2.2, it contains fixes for the problems you've mentioned. The problem is related to API change in version 2.1

If you unable to update the plugin at the moment, you can fix the problem by updating your code as follows:

```
sonarToGerrit (
        sonarURL: env.'SONAR_HOST_URL',
        scoreConfig: [ 
            issueFilterConfig: [
                severity: 'INFO', 
                newIssuesOnly: false, 
                changedLinesOnly: false
                ], 
            category: 'Code-Review', 
            noIssuesScore: 0,
            issuesScore: -1
        ]
    )
```

Comment: We already updated to the latest release. I will test it later on today. Thank you very much :)

Comment: `noIssuesScore` and _Pipeline Syntax_ generator seem to work again. Thank you very much!